# How can I customize Django's admin validation of IntegerFields?

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got an IntegerField in a Django admin model, and sometimes people type in "2,100" instead of "2100" and Django complains "Enter a whole number." Is it possible to override some method that would allow me to strip out commas, dollar signs, etc, so that the number can be correctly parsed as an integer while being intuitive for users? I've tried clean() and clean_fields(), but they don't seem to be what I want, unless I'm using them incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about writing your own custom integer field and using that in place if django's built in version. See the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) for more info. You'll probably want to override the built in `IntegerField`, then maybe [write your own FormField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field).

I suspect it's the validation on the `ModelForm` that's failing when you override `clean()` and `clean_fields()` on the model - the form validation will be kicking in before the model validation.

Try something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import fields

class IntegerPriceFormField(fields.IntegerField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            value = value.replace(",", "").replace("$", "")
        return super(IntegerPriceFormField, self).to_python(value)

class IntegerPriceField(models.IntegerField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': IntegerPriceFormField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(IntegerPriceField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Then you can use IntegerPriceField instead of IntegerField on your model definition.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently going down this route but struggling with which of the myriad methods I need to override, such as get_prep_value, which doesn't seem to be it. Do I need to override `formfield` and provide a custom form too?

Comment: I think you probably do - you might be able to hack it by using an existing FormField, but I think you'd be better writing your own.

Comment: To add to this answer - if you want to display the field with extra markup, e.g. a dollar sign in front (you could adjust this to add commas etc), you can override its `prepare_value` method, e.g. in `class IntegerPriceFormField`, add: `def prepare_value(self, value):  return super(IntegerPriceFormField, self).prepare_value("${0}".format(value))`