# django 1.3 setting custom error_messages on models.IntegerField seems not to work

Tags: python, django, forms

Doing some maintenance on a django 1.3 app.

There is a class Application with (amonst others) an IntegerField:

```
area = models.IntegerField()
```

They are wanting a different error message for invalid entries.
After sifting through all the docs and trying many approaches I haven't managed to resolve this.

For example I tried:

```
area = models.IntegerField(error_messages={'invalid': 'Custom message'})
```

Also:

```
class ApplicationForm(ModelForm):
    area = forms.IntegerField({'invalid': 'Custom message'})

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('...) #all the other fields go here
```

Also other approaches didn't work. I always get the standard "Enter a whole number." error message.

Comment: This question might be similar to [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304126/how-can-i-customize-djangos-admin-validation-of-integerfields)...

Comment: @summea, this seems indeed a possible solution. But I convinced staff that it's too much work for this change request, and that the conventional "Enter whole number" for our case is ok. Thanks